# Why does my form throw an error?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I've been using this php code as part of my form's validation. Its been working fine for the past 6 months. All of a sudden every time I submit the form I keep getting the following custom error message I have setup here:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Our server is under maintenance!<br> If this error persists please contact us directly: <strong>something@test.com</strong>');
```

I've tested the php validation on the form's fields and that seems to work OK.
I haven't changed anything in my php or ajax logic or the html form itself. Can't figure out whats wrong with it.

Here is the php that I use:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 


    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userLastName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userArrival"]) || !isset($_POST["userNumberPeople"]) 
    || !isset($_POST["userPickupLocation"]) || !isset($_POST["userRequest"]) || !isset($_POST["userTourSelection"]))
    {
        die();
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name              = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_LastName          = filter_var($_POST["userLastName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email             = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_TourSelection     = filter_var($_POST["userTourSelection"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Arrival           = filter_var($_POST["userArrival"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_NumberPeople      = filter_var($_POST["userNumberPeople"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_PickupLocation    = filter_var($_POST["userPickupLocation"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Request           = filter_var($_POST["userRequest"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



     $to_Email       = "something@test.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
     $subject        = 'Tour request: '.$user_TourSelection.' '; //Subject line for emails


    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<2) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Name is too short or empty!');
        exit();
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Please enter a valid email address!');
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($user_Request)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Please explain in a few words how you would like us to assist you.');
        exit();
    }


    // message
$message = '<strong>Name:</strong> '.$user_Name.' '.$user_LastName.' <br><br>
            <strong>Date of Arrival:</strong> '.$user_Arrival.' <br><br>
            <strong>Tour:</strong> '.$user_TourSelection.' <br><br>
            <strong>Number of people:</strong> '.$user_NumberPeople.' <br><br>
            <strong>Pick-Up Location:</strong> '.$user_PickupLocation.' <br><br>
            <strong>Request:</strong> '.$user_Request.' 
            ';


//proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    $headers .='Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" ;
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .='X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   @$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Our server is under maintenance!<br> If this error persists please contact us directly: <strong>something@test.com</strong>');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo 'Congratulations '.$user_Name .'! ';
        echo 'We have received your request and we will respond as soon as possible.';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
        //collect input field values
        var user_name       = $('input[name=firstName]').val(); 
        var user_lastname   = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
        var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_numberpeople = $('select#numberofPeople').val();
        var user_pickuplocation = $('select#pickupLocation').val();
        var user_arrivaldate = $('input[name=arrivalDate]').val();
        var user_request    = $('textarea[name=request]').val();
        var user_tourselection = $('#tourSelection option:selected').val();

        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;

       if(user_name==""){ 
            $('input[name=firstName]').addClass("required");
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_lastname==""){ 
            $('input[name=lastName]').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_email=="") {    
            $('input[name=email]').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_numberpeople=="") {    
            $('select#numberofPeople').addClass("required");
            proceed = false;
        }

        if(user_pickuplocation=="") {    
            $('select#pickupLocation').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }


        if(user_arrivaldate=="") {    
            $('input[name=arrivalDate]').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }

        if(user_request=="") {  
            $('textarea[name=request]').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }

        if(user_tourselection=="") {  
            $('select#tourSelection').addClass("required"); 
            proceed = false;
        }



        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if(proceed){

            //deactivate button
            $("#reservation-form button#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled").text('Processing...').addClass("processing-state");

            //data to be sent to server
            var post_data = {

                'userName':user_name, 
                'userLastName':user_lastname, 
                'userEmail':user_email, 
                'userNumberPeople':user_numberpeople, 
                'userPickupLocation':user_pickuplocation, 
                'userArrival':user_arrivaldate, 
                'userRequest':user_request, 
                'userTourSelection':user_tourselection
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('http://www.myurl.com/reservation.php', post_data, function(data){  

                //load success message in #result div element, with slide effect.
                $("#result").hide().html('<span class="success">'+data+'</span>').slideDown();

                $('label').hide();
                $('select').hide();
                $('#reservation-form h2').hide();
                ga('send', 'event', 'tours', 'request-tour', 'Tour-Request-Complete');


            }).fail(function(err) {  //load any error data

                $("#reservation-form button#submit_btn").text('REQUEST FAILED...').removeClass("processing-state").addClass("fail-state");
                $("#result").hide().html('<div class="error">'+err.statusText+'</div>').slideDown();

                ga('send', 'event', 'tours', 'request-tour', 'Tour-Request-Error');

                $( "#reservation-form input, #reservation-form textarea" ).focus(function() {

                    $("#reservation-form button#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled").text('SEND YOUR REQUEST').removeClass("fail-state");
                    $("#result").slideUp();

                }); 

            });
        }
    });


    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("input, textarea").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).removeClass("required"); 
    });


    $("select#tourSelection").change(function() {

        if( $("select#tourSelection").val() != '')

            {$("select#tourSelection").removeClass("required");
            }

    });


        $("select#numberofPeople").change(function() {

        if( $("select#numberofPeople").val() != '')

            {$("select#numberofPeople").removeClass("required");
            }

    });

        $("select#pickupLocation").change(function() {

        if( $("select#pickupLocation").val() != '')

            {$("select#pickupLocation").removeClass("required");
            }

    });




});
```

and the HTML

```
<fieldset id="reservation-form">

<div id="result"></div>
    <h2>Please fill out the form</h2>

    <label for="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="FIRST NAME" />
    </label>

    <label for="lastName">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="LAST NAME" />
    </label>

    <label for="email">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />
    </label>

    <select id="tourSelection">
    <option value="">PLEASE SELECT YOUR TOUR</option>
    <option value="ATHENS TOUR">ATHENS TOUR</option>
    <option value="ATHENS and SOUNION TOUR">ATHENS &amp; SOUNION TOUR</option>
    <option value="ATHENS and CORINTH TOUR">ATHENS &amp; CORINTH TOUR</option>
    <option value="PELOPONNESE TOUR">PELOPONNESE TOUR</option>
    <option value="DELPHI TOUR">DELPHI TOUR</option>
    <option value="DELPHI and THERMOPYLAE TOUR">DELPHI &amp; THERMOPYLAE TOUR</option>
    <option value="VRAVRONA MARATHON and SOUNION TOUR">VRAVRONA MARATHON &amp; SOUNION</option>
    <option value="ATHENS HALF DAY TOUR">ATHENS HALF DAY TOUR</option>
    <option value="CORINTH TOUR">CORINTH TOUR</option>
    <option value="SOUNION TOUR">SOUNION TOUR</option>
    <option value="SOUNION SUNSET TOUR">SOUNION SUNSET TOUR</option>
    <option value="NAFPLIO TOUR">NAFPLIO TOUR</option>
    <option value="DELPHI and METEORA TOUR">DELPHI &amp; METEORA TOUR</option>
    <option value="ARGOLIDA and ANCIENT OLYMPIA TOUR">ARGOLIDA &amp; ANCIENT OLYMPIA TOUR</option>
    <option value="THREE DAY PELOPONNESE TOUR">THREE DAY PELOPONNESE TOUR</option>
    <option value="FOUR DAY PELOPONNESE TOUR">FOUR DAY PELOPONNESE TOUR</option>
    <option value="CUSTOM TOUR">CUSTOM TOUR</option>
    </select>


    <select id="numberofPeople">
        <option value="">TOTAL NUMBER OF PEOPLE IN YOUR PARTY</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="Over 8">Over 8</option>
    </select>


        <select id="pickupLocation">
         <option value="">SPECIFY PICK-UP LOCATION</option>
        <option value="Port">PORT</option>
        <option value="Airport">AIRPORT</option>
        <option value="Hotel">HOTEL</option>
        <option value="Other">OTHER</option>
        </select>




    <label for="arrivalDate">
    <input type="text" name="arrivalDate" id="arrivalDate" placeholder="DATE YOU WISH TO DO THE TOUR" />
    </label>

    <label for="request">
    <textarea name="request" id="request" placeholder="YOUR PERSONAL REQUEST"></textarea>
    </label>

    <label>
    <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">SEND YOUR REQUEST</button>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is that the form does not send the data to the designated email. It always shows the custom error message.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

---

php error reporting shows the following:

```
Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater [file] => Unknown [line] => 0 )
```

**Update** 
After adding `php_flag register_globals off` to my htaccess I'm no longer getting php error messages but its still not submitting. Keeps loading custom error message from line 72 (php code).

Comment: you haven't explain error.

Comment: @fico7489 The form does not submit.

Comment: start by removing `@` error suppressor, use error reporting and post your HTML form and related Ajax.

Comment: The `header` can't have HTML tags! remove them, they don't even show up in response body unless, you read and parse response header.

Comment: @Fred -ii- updated request with more info

Comment: @AdamAzad I've updated my request with more info.

Comment: use error reporting for PHP and check your console for possible errors

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated with error info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are caused by email sending.
Check if mail function is working. The problem can be in the server configuration.

Comment: is that something that I need to check with my hosting provider?

Comment: just create new php file with simple code:
`<?php
var_dump(mail('your_email', 'email test', 'email test - OK!'));
print_r(error_get_last());
?>`

Comment: Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => Undefined variable: headers [file] => /services16/webpages/util/a/t/mydomain.site.myprovider.com/public/reservation.php [line] => 63 )   

What does this mean? (reservation.php is my php code above)

Comment: Change '.' to ';' in line 62: `$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .`

Comment: you mean `$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" ;`  ?

Comment: Yes, because there should be the end of the code line.

Comment: New error message `Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater [file] => Unknown [line] => 0 )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93313/discussion-between-neodan-and-obi-wan).

Comment: You need to set the 'register_globals' to 'off' (`register_globals = off`) in the php.ini. 
P.S. It can take a lot of time to fix all Warnings and Notices in your scripts :|

Comment: added  `php_flag register_globals off` to my htaccess file. I'm not getting any more php errors but its still not submitting. It's loading the custom error message from line 72.

Comment: `<?php var_dump(mail('your_email', 'email test', 'email test - OK!')); print_r(error_get_last()); ?>` Did you try to execute this code? If it does not work then the problem is in the server configuration.

Comment: The code works. I received the test email. Page shows `bool(true)`

Comment: You need to check the server email log and the data which you passing to the mail function.
The php code does not have any errors.

Answer (score 2):

The mail could not be sent in the line

```
@$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Remove the '@' character, and it might give you a message why it was not sent.

Possible problems could be you are not permitted to send mail from the server or something in the configuration of PHP has changed!

**Edit:** To catch the error message, you should use the error_get_last function. Try adding `print_r(error_get_last()); exit;` at line 72.

Comment: Removed the '@' character but that didn't change anything.

Comment: To catch the error message, you should use the `error_get_last` function. Try adding `print_r(error_get_last()); exit; ` after the `if(!$sentMail) {`. This should give you more info. The problem is probably a change to the send_mail functionality or PHP-configuration made by your service provider.

Comment: Checked with service provider. Nothing was changed in the configuration.

Comment: Try @Neodans suggestion in his comment, if it gives you any help.  Otherwise I would suggest you use a more advanced script for sending mail. The PHP mail() function leaves a lot to be wished for. I stopped using it 10 years ago.

Comment: Thank you Hasse. I've updated @Neodans post with the error info I got back.

Comment: Seems like @Neodan beat me to it! Like he says: The last character on line 62 should be a semicolon, not a period.

Comment: When you are finished and it works, add the '@' character again to supress any unwanted warnings and error messages.

Comment: Not getting any more error messages...However its not submitting. Still loads custom message from line 72 from php file.